# Symfony 5.4 Twig misinterpreted and displays {{

Tags: php, symfony, twig

for some views, I have twig that bugs,
some variables are displayed with two braces before
like this one in my code {{ version }}
displays on the interface  {{ 1.0

I'm using symfony 5.4 which runs on PHP7.4

does anyone have an idea of how to fix it?

Thanks

this happens only for a few variables

I just want to display a text in a variable like this {{ myvar }}
know that myvar is 'foo'

In the browser it in the browser it returns me {{foo

Comment: What does `var_dump($myvar)` displays in the controller?

Comment: check if you have unclosed {{ on top of the variable

Comment: @AissamAmezaourou very unlikely as this would throw a twig syntax error

Comment: II have the following folders in my var/cache directory in addition to the prod and dev folders :  ..cw8, ..w6j     => I deleted them manually and that solved the problem

Comment: Can you make a small reproducible example and post it ?